# WPF - DataTrigger animation doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, datatrigger

So I'm trying to make some animations during item removal from ItemsControl which is attached to `ObservableCollectio<Item>`
I know I can't do this in unload event because it's simply too late to perform any animation so I've tried to do this using `DataTrigger`

My `xaml` file looks like this:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyApp:Item}">
        <Border x:Name="ItemBorder">
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Removing}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" From="1.0" To="0.0"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Opacity)" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

and my `Item` class is simply:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private bool removing;
    public bool Removing {
        get
        {
            return removing;
        }
        set
        {
            removing = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Removing"));
        }
    }

    // same with `Name` property
}
```

I would like to start an animation by setting `item.Removing = true` but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where's `Storyboard.TargetName`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to update your animation as below i.e give elementname:

```
              <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Removing}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" From="1.0" To="0.0"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemBorder" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                        </DataTrigger>
             </DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

OR

Try putting animation directly on your border style like below:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyApp:Item}">
    <Border x:Name="ItemBorder">
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        <Border.Style>
           <Style TargetType="Border">
              <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Removing}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                      <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" From="1.0" To="0.0"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger> 
          <Style.Triggers>
        </Style>         
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: bro i tried at my end and it worked just fine... can you check if you are getting any binding errors in output window.. if not can you post your full xaml code ?

Comment: ok, my bad - it's working fine now but I have `Binding` set in `Border.Style` for another purpose and I don't know how to combine those two together - it says that `The property Style is set more than once`

Comment: can you share your code.. it will help me understand it better

Comment: it looks much like the code above, but there's one more line in `Border.Style`: `<Binding Path="Status" Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource StyleConverter}" />` and I would like to leave it there

Comment: so your converter will be returning the instance of some style rt? you can move the trigger we wrote into that style.triggers.. it will work

Comment: but I'd have to add this trigger into every style that converter returns. I would also like to keep those two functionalities separately.

Comment: if you want every style of yours to have this trigger..you can put this in one base trigger and just create other triggers based on that one.

Comment: hmmm, the best approach for me will be the one from my first post, but I will take your advice if I fail at that :)

Comment: updated the answer to make your datatemplate trigger work... hope it helps :)